# Meteor: The Loop of Death

Tags: meteor

I have noticed something really embarrassing with Meteor. When an error occurs inside a method on the server, this makes the entire code of the method to be rerun. This can lead to some unexpected results and some kind of trouble. For instance:

```
Meteor.methods
  'someMethod': ->
  # we insert an element in the database
  Collection.insert({ record: "We want this record to be inserted only once." })

  # We just made a mistake here, let's say that the object is not defined.
  variable = object.property

  return variable
```

What happened in my case is that Meteor throws an error saying that it cannot read the property of undefined (I can see it within the server logs) and then rerun the code of the method repeatedly throwing the same error again. I can see a lot of records inserted on my database when it should have one.

I don't know if there is a way to ask meteor to not rerun the code when an error occurs or some kind of thinking I need to learn while developing an application with it.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a problem with your code, not with Meteor. Can you show what the client code that calls this method looks like?

Comment: and, of course, maybe a solution would be just to wrap statement with *if* block. If the object property is undefined, just do nothing.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is why Meteor rerun the method in loop. I have worked on other frameworks like Django or Symfony2 and when something goes wrong, it throws an error but it does not rerun the previous code. In the case above, if someone do a little mistake, we fill our database with plenty of useless records which is embarassing.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior. Indeed I saw it some time ago, but don't remember why this was happening. Probably it is a problem with your code as @AndrewMao suggests.